# Case insensitive database support for a Java web application

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, hibernate, case-sensitive

We are building a Java web application which uses Hibernate as its ORM.  We support three major RDBMS, including SQL Server, Oracle, and MySQL (and HSQL, additionally).  Currently, we do not do any special handling for case sensitivity of character (column) data, which means this behavior is being determined by the particular database a customer chooses to use.  For example, MySQL, which uses the default collation `latin1_swedish_ci` is case insensitive, whereas Oracle is case sensitive.  This means that for a customer running MySQL the user `bob` and `Bob` would be treated identically, while a customer running Oracle would actually have two different users.

We would like to standardize behavior across all customer databases.  One option for handling this outside the database would be to always compare the lowercase version of all column data when doing a `WHERE`, `LIKE`, or any other comparison, against a lowercase version of an input.  This would work, but would be tedious and would add debt to the app code.  A lowercase column could be added to the database as an optimization.

**The question:**

A better alternative to hacking the app layer would be to handle case sensitivity in the database itself.  There are plenty of resources in the literature on how to handle case sensitive collation for a given RDBMS.  **But how would one go about handling configuration for a given RDBMS from Hibernate?**

Is there some way to cover all our customer database configurations for case sensitivity from Hibernate, or would we need to use database-specific setup scripts for each of our customers?  Any pointers to code which configures a database for case sensitivity through Hibernate would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if this would help, do have a look at [**Oracle – Case Insensitive Sorts & Compares**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/oracle-case-insensitive-sorts-compares/) You might want to think about performance though.

Comment: You have to do it on database server side, otherwise indexing will not work and you will get poor performance. Or when you do not care about case sensitivity, then you can simply store all strings in uppercase.

Comment: The thing is, we would want to always display a string to the user in the original form which he entered.  So user `Fred` should see `Fred` and not `FRED` or `fred` when he logs in.

Comment: @LalitKumarB Thanks for the Oracle link, we will definitely read that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are you talking about table/column/function names or are you talking about string data contained in the tables?

Comment: @MT0 I am referring to string (character) data contained in the tables.  I will update my question since this seems to be unclear.